# Extract data from xml tag using python

Tags: python, xml

I wish to extract some ids(doi, pmcid and pmid) from a .xml file from the record tag using python:

xml file:

```
<pmcids status="ok">
    <request idtype="doi" dois="" versions="yes" showaiid="no">
        <warning>no e-mail provided</warning>
        <warning>no tool provided</warning>
        <echo>ids=10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0054577</echo>
    </request>
    <record requested-id="10.1371/JOURNAL.PONE.0054577"     pmcid="PMC3557238" pmid="23382917" doi="10.1371/journal.pone.0054577">
        <versions><version pmcid="PMC3557238.1" current="true"/>
        </versions>
    </record>
</pmcids>
```

I have tried the following code of python :

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

xmlDoc = open('garbage_collector/tmp.xml', 'r')
xmlDocData = xmlDoc.read()
xmlDocTree = etree.XML(xmlDocData)

for ingredient in xmlDocTree.iter('record'):
    print ingredient[0].text
```

I want pmcid, doi and pmid as output in the form of string

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation), you could do

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(input_xml)
t = soup.find('record')
```

where `input_xml` is the xml to be examined in string form.

We find the `record` tag with the `find()` function and store it in a variable `t`. The attributes of the `<record>` tag can now be accessed by indexing `t`.

```
print(t['pmcid'])
print(t['doi'])
print(t['pmid'])
```

would print

```
PMC3557238
10.1371/journal.pone.0054577
23382917
```